# terraform multiple NSG using csv

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to follow the solution given here [How I can avoid multiple loops with Terraform for_each and dynamic for resource azurerm_network_security_group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406160/how-i-can-avoid-multiple-loops-with-terraform-for-each-and-dynamic-for-resource#comment107496004_60539818)

Here is my module: Module-Azure-Nsg-V3/main.tf

```
locals {
  # read csv file
  list_of_csv_lines = csvdecode(file(var.csv_file_name))
  # collect all nsg names , (Unique)
  all_nsg_names = distinct([for item in local.list_of_csv_lines : item.nsg_name])
  # collect all nsg names other syntax , (Unique)
  all_nsg_names_again = distinct(local.list_of_csv_lines[*].nsg_name)


  # Loop over all unique names ---> for item in local.all_nsg_names : 
  # create a key of nsg name item ----> "${item}" =>
  # And to now fill value in that dictionary item key, 
  # Loop over list of csv lines  
  # pick the line 
  # if nsg_name matches item
  combine = {
      for item in local.all_nsg_names : 
        "${item}" => [
          for line in local.list_of_csv_lines : line 
          if item == line.nsg_name
        ]
  }
  


}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "this" {
  for_each = local.combine

  name                = each.key
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  dynamic "security_rule" {
     for_each = each.value
    
        content {
                name                        = security_rule.value["nsg_name"]
                priority                    = security_rule.value["priority"]
                direction                   = security_rule.value["direction"]
                access                      = security_rule.value["access"]
                protocol                    = security_rule.value["protocol"]
                source_port_range           = security_rule.value["source_port_range"]
                destination_port_range      = security_rule.value["destination_port_range"]
                source_address_prefix       = security_rule.value["source_address_prefix"]
                destination_address_prefix  = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
          }
  }

}



output "all-nsg-names-in-output" {
 value = local.all_nsg_names
}
output "all-nsg-names-in-output-again" {
 value = local.all_nsg_names_again
}
output "combine-output"{
  value = local.combine
}
```

Here is my module: Module-Azure-Nsg-V3/variables.tf

```
variable "csv_file_name" {
  type = string
  default = null
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource Group"
  type = string
  default = null
}

variable "location" {
   description = "enviroment in which you are working"
   type = string
   default = null
}
```

Now I am using above mention module to create NSG.

Here is my nsg_rules.csv

```
nsg_name,rulename,priority,direction,access,protocol,source_port_range,destination_port_range,source_address_prefix,destination_address_prefix 
nsg01,Rule01,100,Inbound,Allow,Tcp,80,*,*,*
nsg01,Rule02,110,Inbound,Allow,Tcp,443,*,*,*
nsg02,Rule01,100,Inbound,Allow,Tcp,80,*,*,*
nsg02,Rule02,110,Inbound,Allow,Tcp,443,*,*,*
nsg03,Rule01,100,Inbound,Allow,Tcp,80,*,*,*
```

This is variables.tf file

```
variable "csv_file_name" {
  type = string
  default = "nsg_rules.csv"
}

variable "location" {
   description = "enviroment in which you are working"
   type = string
   default = "eastus"
}


variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource Group"
  type = string
  default = "terraform_rg"
}
```

And main.tf

```
module "Module-Azure-Nsg-V3" {
  source  = "./Module-Azure-Nsg-V3"
  csv_file_name = var.csv_file_name
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
 }

output "display_this" {
   value = module.Module-Azure-Nsg-V3.all-nsg-names-in-output
}

output "display_this_again" {
   value = module.Module-Azure-Nsg-V3.all-nsg-names-in-output-again
}
output "all-nsg-rules" {
   value = module.Module-Azure-Nsg-V3.combine-output
}
```

But I get errors.

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on Module-Azure-Nsg-V3/main.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "this":
│   46:                 destination_address_prefix  = security_rule.value["destination_address_prefix"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ security_rule.value is object with 10 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`destination_address_prefix` is actually `"destination_address_prefix "` - you have **extra space** in your csv file after `destination_address_prefix`.

Comment: Still error ╷
│ Error: creating/updating Network Security Group: (Name "nsg02" / Resource Group "terraform_rg-dev"): network.SecurityGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidRequestFormat" Message="Cannot parse the request." Details=[{"code":"DuplicateResourceName","message":"Resource /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/ has two child resources with the same name (nsg02)."}]

Comment: I agree you helped me . And i figured out further issue as well  This line need to be replaced name  = security_rule.value["nsg_name"] with security_rule.value["rulename"]